# Differences between format long and format long g

Tags: matlab, decimal, rounding, floating-accuracy

I searched differences between format long and format long g in Matlab.But I'm not sure exactly what the differences are between them.Does the difference between them affect accuracy?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands `format X` in Matlab affect the *display* of text.

So `format short` will display 4 digits after the decimal point. This is the default display option. The command `format long` will display more digits after the decimal point. The addition of a `G` will tell Matlab to additionally display in scientific notation if it is more compact.

There is not difference in terms of computed values or accuracy, just display. From the `doc format` or here [Display Format Matlab article](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-format-for-numeric-values.html):

> format does not affect how MATLAB computations are done. Computations
>       on float variables, namely single or double, are done in appropriate
>       floating point precision, no matter how those variables are displayed. 
>       Computations on integer variables are done natively in integer.

Answer (score 1):

`format long` basically a fixed decimal format. It always show 7 digits after decimal point for single accuracy and 15 digits after decimal point for double accuracy.

`format longG` are going to show **up to** 7 digits after decimal point for single accuracy and 15 digits after decimal point for double accuracy. But, if there is a zeros behind, it won't be shown. So, `longG` is more compact.

It won't affect the accuracy for calculation. Accuracy are depends on `single` or `double` precision.

Look at my example below, if I've saved `a` as 12.999012 and called for `pi`, MATLAB will response like this :

[Format longG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/865nz.png)

[Format long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ3am.png)

If you are also asking for the `format short` and `format shortG`, the difference just the 4 digits behind decimal point.

Cheers!